# Uppercase object keys have NaN values

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm creating this object:

```
const Tamano_Inicial = 50

var jugadorNuevo = 
    {
        id: socket.id,
        Color: Math.random(),
        Tamano: Tamano_Inicial,
        Puntuacion: 0,
        Posicion: { x: 1, y: 1 },
        Velocidad: {x: 0, y:0}
    };
console.log(jugadorNuevo) // outputs {..., Posicion: {x: NaN, y: NaN}, Velocidad: {x: NaN, y: NaN}}
```

Both members of both `Velocidad` and `Posicion` have `NaN` values.

But when I change it to this (lowercase):

```
const Tamano_Inicial = 50

var jugadorNuevo = 
    {
        id: socket.id,
        color: Math.random(), // Tono de color entre 0 y 1 (hue)
        tamano: Tamano_Inicial,
        puntuacion: 0,
        posicion: { x: 1, y: 1 },
        velocidad: {x: 0, y:0}
    };
    console.log(jugadorNuevo);
```

It properly outputs `{...,posicion: {x: 0, y: 0}, velocidad: {x: 0, y: 0}}`.

Why does this happen?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this behavior; I get `Posicion: {x:1, y:1}` and `Velocidad: {x:0, y:0}`.

What environment are you using? Node, some browser, something else?

Comment: @ameed I'm using node. My question is, regardless of whatever is around that block of code, if I print the object right after it's created, it should keep its values no matter what?

Comment: it is not a JavaScript issue, probably you have sort of parser?

Comment: @NedkoDimitrov What do you mean? You're saying a parser might be tampering with the values? I'm using VS Code, with some lint extensions.

Comment: Yes, for example TypeScript is converted to JavaScript with a parser. You might have that one on other. Add your settings to your question e.g. package.json webpack.config.js...

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a bug somewhere else in the code. It initially puzzled me because on VS Code, if you print an object, the values of its members are shown real-time. So even though, initially, the object initialization was correct, when I saw the object representation on VS Code it was already corrupted (by another block of code).